# How declare the data in column mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone help me, I wanna declare the data from column "status".
If 'green' then the value is 1.
If 'yellow' the value is 2.
If 'red' the value is 3.

And then all of that value can make line graph using PHP language.

```
   name: 'Data Status',
             data: [
                        <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM monitoring";
                        $result = mysqli_query($koneksi, $sql);
                        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                         ?>
                            <?php echo $data["status"]?>, <?php
                        }?>
                    ]
```

But I know the data cannot load properly because the type data is string.

```
+---------+------------+----------+----------+
    | id_data | time       | status   |   date   |
    +---------+------------+----------+----------+
    | 1       | 05.00      |   green  | 01-01-18 | 
    | 2       | 05.30      |   green  | 02-01-18 | 
    | 3       | 05.30      |   red    | 03-01-18 | 
    | 4       | 05.30      |   green  | 04-01-18 | 
    | 5       | 05.15      |   yellow | 05-01-18 | 
    | 6       | 05.20      |   yellow | 06-01-18 | 
    | 7       | 05.11      |   red    | 07-01-18 | 
    | 8       | 05.05      |   red    | 08-01-18 | 
    | 9       | 05.22      |   green  | 09-01-18 | 
    +---------+------------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM monitoring";
 $result = mysqli_query($koneksi, $sql);
 while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     switch ($data["status"]){
         case 'green':
             $value = 1;
             break
         case 'yellow':
             $value = 2;
             break;
         case 'red':
             $value = 3;
             break;
         default:
             $value = 0;
             break;
      }
      echo $data["status"] . ' ' . $value;
 }
```

Comment: You are wellcome

Answer (score 0):

Possible the easiest would be a `case` statement in the sql

```
SELECT 
    `id_data`,
    `time`,
    `date`,
    case 
        when `status`='green' then 1
        when `status`='yellow' then 2
        when `status`='red' then 3
    end as `status`
    FROM `monitoring`
```